# Zuul router with Spring application.yml routes won't work as expected

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

Hello I tried to make routing with zuul work I looked at the docs and read this part.
application.yml.

```
 zuul:
  routes:
    users: /myusers/**
```

This means that http calls to "/myusers" get forwarded to the "users" service (for example "/myusers/101" is forwarded to "/101").
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html

My application.yml looks like this

```
zuul:
routes:
    home:
        path: /home/**
        serviceId: SKELETONPAGE
        stripPrefix: false
```

The /home path won't take me to the skeletonpage service and this service will instead be mapped to /skeletonpage. Am I filling in the properties wrong or is there another thing that I may forgot?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `stripPrefix: false` means that your request to `/home/index.html` will result in request being forwarded to `SKELETONPAGE/home/index.html`.

With `stripPrefix: true` it will route to `SKELETONPAGE/index.html`

Comment: I added the stripPrefix: false because I need the HTML the acces javascript files in the SKELETONPAGE service through the ZUUL router